# laravel model attribute updated_at show wrong format

Tags: laravel, date, model, php-carbon

when i print the `updated_at` field into the views, it returns something like this:

```
{ "date": "2017-12-08 15:07:26.000000", "timezone_type": 3, "timezone": "Australia/Melbourne" }
```

why this field behave like this?
i check the model and i explicitly cast the field to carbon (`expiry_date` was there before and it's a correct format):

```
protected $dates = [
  'expiry_date',
  'updated_at',
];
```

but the issue still persists.
do you have idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: that indeed is a `Carbon` object. How do you print the `updated_at`?

Answer (score 0):

try setting the date format on your model.

`protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';`

Answer (score 0):

If you `echo`, or do something else to either implicitly or explicitly call the `__toString()` method, you'll get the plain date.

The format that you're showing, however, is what you see when you `json_encode()` a Carbon object.

Make sure that whatever you're doing to display your data is not using `json_encode()` on the date.